# How to retrieve all users and all roles from Kohana 3 using Auth module?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana, kohana-3.3

Can I recive list of all users with all roles? I need to know **all** roles of every user in my database. I am using Auth module in Kohana 3.3 with ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. But I can not understand why you want to do such a thing suboptimal.

**1. FULL ORM:**

```
$users = ORM::factory('Auth_User')->find_all();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $roles = $user->roles->find_all();
    foreach($roles as $role)
        $role->name;
}
```

**2. Universal SQL** (hint):

```
SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_roles USING(user_id) 
INNER JOIN roles USING(role_id) 
ORDER BY users.name
```

Results:

- user_1 role_1
- user_1 role_2
- user_2 role_x

**3. Easy display SQL** (but you change code on every adding new role)

`SELECT users.*, IF(r1.user_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS role1, 
    IF(r2.user_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS role2, 
    IF(rn.user_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS rolen
  FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id FROM user_roles where role_id = 1) AS r1 USING(user_id)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id FROM user_roles where role_id = 2) AS r2 USING(user_id)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id FROM user_roles where role_id = n) AS rn USING(user_id)`

Results:
`username | role1 | role2 | rolen
user1    | 1     | 0     | 0
user2    | 0     | 1     | 1`